# the relation between the limitation of variable $x$ and that of the derivative of variable

Tags: linear-algebra, limits, derivatives

if we have $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}|x_i(t)-x_j(t)|=0$, whether we can conclude that $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}|v_i(t)-v_j(t)|=0$ ? where $x$ is a vector, and $x_i$ is the $i$-th of vector $x$ and $v_i(t)$ is the derivation of $x_i(t)$.$|\cdot|$ represent the absolute value.

if not, please tell me the reason.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that $v_i(t) - v_j(t)$ is the derivative of $x_i(t) - x_j(t)$ so what you're essentially asking is: *If $\lim_{t \to \infty}|f(t)| = 0$ does this imply $\lim_{t \to \infty}|f'(t)| = 0$?*

The answer to that is no, for example $f(t) = e^{-t}\sin(e^t)$ is a counter example.

Comment: it is clear, thank you.